# ffmpeg stream mp4 file to Instagram live

Tags: video, ffmpeg, instagram, rtmp

I created a live stream session on instafeed.me then used `ffmpeg` to send an MP4 file to the stream. But I get IO error.

The command is

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 256M -re -i "1.mp4" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 504x896 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmps://live-upload.instagram.com:443/rtmp/XXXXXXX?s_sw=0&s_vt=ig&a=XXXXXXX"
```

The output is

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-05-04-5767a2e Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 43.100 / 56. 43.100
  libavcodec     58. 82.100 / 58. 82.100
  libavformat    58. 42.102 / 58. 42.102
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 80.100 /  7. 80.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.102
  Duration: 01:05:43.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1729 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1594 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] using SAR=256/81e=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=18 lookahead_threads=6 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=30 keyint_min=3 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=400 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1500 vbv_bufsize=6000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmps://live-upload.instagram.com:443/rtmp/XXXXX?s_sw=0&s_vt=ig&a=XXXX':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 504x896 [SAR 256:81 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 400 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.82.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 1500000/0/400000 buffer size: 6000000 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.82.100 libmp3lame
[tls @ 000001cf5bb3c200] Error in the push function.0:02.90 bitrate= 179.5kbits/s speed=0.957x
av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 000001cf5bd0e980] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 000001cf5bd0e980] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmps://live-upload.instagram.com:443/rtmp/XXXXXX?s_sw=0&s_vt=ig&a=XXXXXXX: I/O error
frame=   66 fps= 20 q=37.0 Lsize=      89kB time=00:00:03.26 bitrate= 224.1kbits/s speed=0.965x
video:66kB audio:51kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[tls @ 000001cf5bb3c200] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] frame I:3     Avg QP:31.09  size:  9012
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] frame P:63    Avg QP:33.47  size:  1733
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] mb I  I16..4: 78.1%  0.0% 21.9%
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] mb P  I16..4: 11.0%  0.0%  0.6%  P16..4: 14.7%  3.6%  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:69.6%
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] final ratefactor: 30.81
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 16.6% 12.9% 0.9% inter: 1.8% 0.9% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] i16 v,h,dc,p: 56% 12% 18% 14%
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 43%  7% 26%  4%  3%  9%  1%  6%  1%
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] i8c dc,h,v,p: 76%  4% 19%  1%
[libx264 @ 000001cf5ba53300] kb/s:389.26
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram apparently does not like MP3. Use AAC instead. Replace `-acodec libmp3lame`/`-c:a libmp3lame` with `-c:a aac`.